# teradata default database query

Tags: sql, database, teradata, default

If I run the following queries in Teradata:

DATABASE DB1_DEFAULT;

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN DB2_NOT_DEFAULT.TABLE2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID;

Does this SELECT query by any way make DB2_NOT_DEFAULT the default database, or will DB1_DEFAULT continue to be the default database until I issue a second DATABASE command?

Comment: The latter.  DB1_Default is your default database until your session ends or you specify a different default db.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have done DATABASE DB1_DEFAULT; so DB1_DEFAULT will be your default database . But for TABLE2 you specifically mentioned DB2_NOT_DEFAULT, it can fetch data from that. It will not change your default database.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.